# Components of $\sigma$ algebras

Tags: measure-theory

I previously thought that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^n = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which I just realized was false!

I'm wondering whether the following weaker statements are true:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\prod_{i = 1}^n \Omega_i$, $\mathcal{F}_i$ be the family of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ each projected to it's $i$th coordinate, then

- $\mathcal{F}_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_i$
- $\prod_{i = 1}^n \mathcal{F}_i \subseteq \mathcal{F}$

I'm finding this intuitively clear but tricky to prove (particularly the second).

Comment: I see, one inclusion is true, but the misconception you had was "every Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a product of $n$ Borel sets from $\mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes thats right.

Comment: What do you mean by "restricted to its $i$th coordinate"?  Do you mean the projection?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true.  Let $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2 = \{a,b\}$ be a set with two points, and let
$$\mathcal{F} = \{\emptyset, \{(a,a)\}, \{(a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}, \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2\}.$$
Then $\mathcal{F}_1 = \mathcal{F}_2 = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ which is not a $\sigma$-algebra.  Moreover $\mathcal{F}_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2$ contains the set $\{a\} \times \{a,b\} = \{(a,a),(a,b)\}$ which is not in $\mathcal{F}$.